# Can't get map to display on page, Openlayers ASP.NET core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, web-applications, openlayers

I have tried to get it to display but it just shows me the html formatting not the map. In the script part when a simple map display code is entered it displays the map but when any other function is added it stops functioning. I haven't been able to recreate what is available on this page: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

Please help

The sample map code that displays correctly:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

The code that doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Draw and Modify Features</title>
    <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
    <style>
        .map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
        <select id="type">
            <option value="Point">Point</option>
            <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
            <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
            <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var raster = new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        });

        var source = new VectorSource();
        var vector = new VectorLayer({
            source: source,
            style: new Style({
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
                }),
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: '#ffcc33',
                    width: 2,
                }),
                image: new CircleStyle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: '#ffcc33',
                    }),
                }),
            }),
        });

        var map = new Map({
            layers: [raster, vector],
            target: 'map',
            view: new View({
                center: [-11000000, 4600000],
                zoom: 4,
            }),
        });

        var modify = new Modify({ source: source });
        map.addInteraction(modify);

        var draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
        var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

        function addInteractions() {
            draw = new Draw({
                source: source,
                type: typeSelect.value,
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
            snap = new Snap({ source: source });
            map.addInteraction(snap);
        }

        /**
         * Handle change event.
         */
        typeSelect.onchange = function () {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            map.removeInteraction(snap);
            addInteractions();
        };

        addInteractions();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are using the full build library instead of importing from modules you need to use the full build syntax e.g. ol.Map, ol.layer.Tile  instead of Map TileLayer, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to use syntax as Mike pointed out.

Example:  instead of this

```
var raster = new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        });
```

you should use full build syntax

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            });
```

Or just copy past Mike's solution above

this line:

```
var raster = new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        });
```

and that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to make module syntax code work with the full build to define the equivalent variable names at the start of your code

```
var TileLayer    = ol.layer.Tile;
var OSM          = ol.source.OSM;
var VectorSource = ol.source.Vector;
var VectorLayer  = ol.layer.Vector;
var Style        = ol.style.Style;
var Fill         = ol.style.Fill;
var Stroke       = ol.style.Stroke;
var CircleStyle  = ol.style.Circle;
var Map          = ol.Map;
var View         = ol.View;
var Modify       = ol.interaction.Modify;
var Draw         = ol.interaction.Draw;
var Snap         = ol.interaction.Snap;
```